# How can i do multiple search using different dropdowns to display tasks releated to search in php mysql?

Tags: php, select, dropdown

[image]

In the above image there are four dropdowns. If I select an user from the drop down it will shows the tasks related to that user in same way, if I select one project it will displays the tasks related to that project and so on.

Now, my problem is I want to select multiple which means, if I select user and a project then it will show the tasks related to that project and as well as user and so on.

**Here is my code to filter:**

```
//filter task by user javascript file
function filter_user_task( id ) {
    jQuery(function($) {
         // alert(id);
         //assign its choosen id to hidden input
     $('#memberid').val(id)
    var data = {
        'action': 'AJAXFilterUserTask',
        'Id': id
    };
    $.post( ajaxurl, data, function(response) {
        if(response) {
            jQuery(".userList").empty();
            jQuery(".userList").append(response); }
        }
    );
}
```

**In my php ajax callback function:**

```
function AJAXFilterUserTask() {
    global $wpdb;   
    /* required for  task */    

    $IdeasDB = $wpdb->get_results('SELECT * FROM OCTM_Ideas ORDER BY Priority, Due');
    $this->Priority = $this->ArrayReduce($wpdb->get_results('select Value as Id,Name from OCTM_Meta where Type = "Priority" order by Value', ARRAY_A) );
    $this->TasksTypes = $this->ArrayReduce( $wpdb->get_results('SELECT Value AS Id, Name FROM OCTM_Meta WHERE Type = "TaskType" ORDER BY Value', ARRAY_A) );
    $this->TasksStatus = $this->ArrayReduce( $wpdb->get_results('SELECT Value AS Id, Name FROM OCTM_Meta WHERE Type = "TaskStatus" ORDER BY Value', ARRAY_A) );
    $this->Ideas = array();
    if ($IdeasDB)
    {
        foreach ($IdeasDB as $Idea)
        {
            $this->Ideas[$Idea->Id] = $Idea;
        }
    }   
    $this->TasksStatusClass = array
        (
            1 => 'label-danger',
            2 => 'label-warning',
            3 => 'label-success',
            4 => 'label-primary',
        );
        $this->PriorityClass = array
        (
            1 => 'label-danger',
            2 => 'label-warning',
            3 => 'label-success',
        );
    $user_id = $_POST['Id'];
        $sql = '';



        if($user_id != 'all') {
            $sql ="SELECT * from OCTM_Tasks where Member = '$user_id' ";
        } else {
            $sql ="SELECT * from OCTM_Tasks where Status !=3 and Status != 4 LIMIT 0 , 3";
        }
        $res = $wpdb->get_results($sql); 

        if ($res) :  foreach ($res as $Task) : $MemberData = get_userdata($Task->Member); ?>
        <tr class="user_<?php echo $Task->Member; ?> user_list">
            <td>
                <?php $this->DBDecode($this->Ideas[$Task->Idea]->Idea); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="label <?php print $this->PriorityClass[$Task->Priority]; ?> label-mini"><?php print $this->Priority[$Task->Priority]; ?></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php $this->DBDecode($Task->Task); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php print $this->TasksTypes[$Task->Type]; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <span class="label <?php print $this->TasksStatusClass[$Task->Status]; ?> label-mini"><?php print $this->TasksStatus[$Task->Status]; ?></span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php print $MemberData->display_name; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php print $Task->Estimate; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php print $Task->Spent; ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <?php print mysql2date('m/d/Y', $Task->Due); ?>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal-1" data-id="<?php print $Task->Id; ?>" data-action="OCTMTaskEdit">Edit</a>


                <?php 
                /* ----------- my custom delete option for deleteing a task ---------- */
                if(current_user_can('administrator')) :
                        $delRow = "delete_project_{$Task->Id}"; 
                            echo "<form method='POST'><input type='submit' name=$delRow value='delete' class='btn btn-danger' /> </form>";

                    if(isset($_POST[$delRow])){
                            $wpdb->delete( 'octm_tasks', array( 'ID' => $Task->Id ) );
                        }   
                        endif;  
                /* ----------- End of my custom delete option for deleteing a task ---------- */
                ?>  
            </td>

                <!----------- my custom comment option for a task ---------->

            <td><!-- <span id="notification_count"></span> -->
                <a class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal-1cmt" data-id="<?php print $Task->Id; ?>" data-action="OCTMTaskComment">Add Comment</a><br />
                <a class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" href="#myModal-viewcmt" data-id="<?php print $Task->Id; ?>" data-action="OCTMTaskCommentView">View Comment</a>
            </td>
                <!-----------End of my custom delete option for deleteing a task ---------->

        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; 
        else : 
        ?>
        <tr>

            <td colspan="9">
                <?php _e('No tasks found.', $this->TextDomain); ?>
            </td>

        </tr>
<?php endif;
    // return true;     
        exit;
    }
```

This is the function I have used while filtering by user in this same way I have used other filters.

Comment: Give your query. Then only we can help you

Comment: okay wait a minute

Comment: @aravind, You have to pass all your filter values in same query. It will work with ajax on select of any dropdown call ajax and pass all dropdown values(if selected then pass values else pass null or 0), based on that use that query. There should be only one query should be executed every and in where condition of query pass those selected variables from which you have received from ajax call.

Comment: Ok. I dont understand the code. But the concept is, pass all the dropdown values as arguments in the ajax call & if any value in that is not null, then write condition based on the selection